# How do I incorporate a try and catch to this array list?

Tags: java, try-catch

When I enter the user input of anything other than a positive integer, it will crash. I tried to incorporate a try and catch before the Scanner, but the max_players and input for the for loop had a red underline.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NameInput {

public static void main(String [] args) {



    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("How many players are going to play the game?");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max_players = input.nextInt();


    for(int i = 1; i <= max_players; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nPlayer " + i + ", please state your name: ");
        String name =input.next();
        players.add(name);
    }


    System.out.println(players.size());
    System.out.println(players);
  }

}
```

UPDATE: Why does the question re-appear after I have given the user its names?

```
import java.util.*;

public class NameInput {

public static void main(String [] args) {

ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
int max_players = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("How many players are going to play the game?");
    try {
        max_players = input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ee) {
        System.out.println("try again");
        input.nextLine ();
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= max_players; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nPlayer " + i + ", please state your name: ");
        String name =input.next();
        players.add(name);
    }
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is reproducible?  I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Maybe he means `How many players are going to play the game?
ss
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: The main issue I am having is this: "How many players are going to play the game?"
e
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at NameInput.main(NameInput.java:13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a loop and catching the exception

```
int max_players = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("How many players are going to play the game?");
    try {
        max_players = input.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ee) {
        System.out.println("try again");
        input.nextLine ();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) you need to break after sucessfully getting the input.  2) the `for ` loop should be after the `while` loop

Comment: I do have the for loop after the while loop. Also, where should I put the break?

Comment: Your `for` loop is in the `while` loop.  *where should I put the break?* - exactly where I put it.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong. Sorry, I am sort of inexperienced in Java. I appreciate the support and patience. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to incorporate a try and catch before the Scanner, but the max_players and input for the for loop had a red underline.

To pass this issue, you need to declare max_players outside of the try-catch block, and initial a default value for it.

Comment: I don't see a `try-catch` block in the OP's current code.

Comment: Yes, I know. But he mentioned it inside the part that I quoted.

Comment: I am having an issue where it will ask for the players on loop.

Comment: I run your code and seem everything ok, can you make it more clear about the issue you meet?

Comment: @DangNguyen After I type in each name, it will ask the same question again with "How many players are going to play the game?"

Comment: ah I get it. So you use a `while(true)` which mean it will loop forever. So you should do it like this `boolean stop = false;while (!stop) {` and then `players.add(name); stop = true;`

Comment: I was able to get it solved. Thank you for the support.